# Regular Expression to exclude Word ending with _OK

Tags: regex

For the below entries i want to exclude words ending with `_OK`
I have found a regex which matches words ending with `_OK`
But I want to find the opposite

This RegEx Matches word ending with `_OK`

```
\b(\w+(?:_OK))\b
```

Inputs:

```
SMHST_BI_V2016AUG
SMHST BI V2016AUG_OK
SMHST_BI_V2016SEP
SMHST_BI_V2016SEP_OK
```

Comment: This may or may not be possible from within the regex, depending on which library or programming language you are using (you need "negative lookahead", which isn't always available).  However, you can certainly use the regex you have and then, from the controlling code, process all lines that *don't* match.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, is `SMHST BI V2016AUG_OK` a typo, or would you want to treat `SMHST` and `BI` as valid matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
\b\w+(?<!_OK)\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bPLoAP/1)

As suggested by Wiktor, you can make the `+` possessive in order to be faster.

---

Also, note that most of the time, this kind of generic requests can be handled with a simple `!Contains()`

Comment: With this approach, I'd use `\b\w++(?<!_OK)\b`, a possessive quantifier will make the regex engine grab the word chars without the backtracking option, and `_OK` will only be checked for *once* after those word chars are matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tested it, it seems twice faster! Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, just mind that possessive quantifiers are not supported by some engines that support lookehinds (Python `re`, e.g.). That is why a lookahead version is more cross-engine compatible.

Comment: It would not have occurred to me to use negative lookbehind at the *end* of the match!  Please add notes about which regex engines support `(?<!...)` and `++`, though, negative lookbehind definitely isn't universal and I'd never heard of `++` before.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways.

Using a negative lookahead ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8bJJhT/1)):

```
\b(?!\w*_OK\b)\w+\b
```

or a negative lookbehind:

```
\b\w+\b(?<!_OK)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/8bJJhT/2)

The first option is good to use with most NFA regex engines (e.g. PCRE, JavaScript, Python, .NET, Java, Oniguruma/Onigmo, ICU), while the second one can be used only with those supporting lookbehinds (.NET, PCRE, Python, Java, ICU, Oniguruma/Onigmo). Note that in RE2 and Go, lookarounds are not supported at all.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?!\w*_OK\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ word chars after the current position followed with `_OK` followed with a word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars followed with
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

The `\b\w+\b(?<!_OK)` pattern is similar, but the `(?<!_OK)` negative lookbehind is triggered only once after a whole word is matched, and fails the match if there is an `_OK`  char sequence before the current position (that is, the trailing word boundary after the word matched with `\w+`).

Comment: Once again, you're faster; well done! Is there any difference between your lookbehind and mine or do they behave the same?

Comment: I posted a comment about how to make your pattern faster.

Answer (score 0):

The "lookahead" and/or "lookbehind" features that you need, to do this from within a regex, are not always available.  Instead, you can invert the outer control logic, processing only lines that *don't* match.  For instance, in Perl you would write

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next if /_OK$/;
    # if we get here, $_ does _not_ end in "_OK"
}
```

Or, from a shell prompt,

```
grep -v '_OK$' < file_to_process | further_steps
```

As you can see, this technique may also allow you to use a much simpler regex.

(Perl regexes do have lookahead/lookbehind; I'm just using it because of its very convenient notation for the "outer control logic".)